# In javascript how to get value in variable from input textboxes with id having incremented integer

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, inputbox

Amongst `n input` text boxes having ids with an incremented integer. Example 
first textbox is `text_box_1_name` and 10th is `text_box_10_name`.
I need to get the value from these textboxes using a for loop.

```
function exportCSV(filename)
{
    var csv = [];
    var number_of_names = document.getElementById("text_no_of_names").value;
    csv.push(number_of_names)
    var temp = document.getElementById("text_box_2_name")
    // Value is available in temp var if id is written directly
    for (var i = 0 ; i < number_of_names ; i++) {
        var temp =document.getElementById("text_box_"+i+"name").value
        // How to increment such id
        csv.push(temp)
    }
    downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename); // Function ahead to download csv
}
```

Comment: So whats the problem? better would be to assign common class

Comment: You have already identified that you need to use a for loop, so where is your attempt at this?

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far, what error do you get and what is the desired output. A snippet could be nice to try to help you !

Comment: How to increment id in the loop in JS

Comment: @OmkarKekre , the answer isn't crazy complicated to create -- but the principle of StackOverflow is to help solve problems not to do the work. (there's a distinction there)  Can you please provide some JavaScript code that you have tried? And from that we can help you in identifying where a problem may be.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but *you need to help yourself first*. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't** working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I have added the code for reference

Comment: By your code, it looks like a typo may be your issue... you're missing an underscore before 'name' `var temp =document.getElementById("text_box_"+i+"_name").value` ... the for loop will automatically increment the `i` variable until it reaches the described limit (it's the `i++` part of the loop that controls the incrementation)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But that's not a problem. I have change the case still doesn't work

Comment: Also check out that your loop is using `number_of_names` not `number_of_node` -- otherwise, i don't know where you're getting the value for `number_of_names` (also if you're using `number_of_node` as your value, you will have to use `parseInt()` to convert it from a string into a number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [querySelectorAll](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp) to select the `input`s which `id`'s start with `text_box` and loop through them with [.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp):

```
function exportCSV(filename)
{
    var csv = [];

    [...document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="text_box"]')].forEach(function(e){
      csv.push(e.value);
    });

    downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename); // Function ahead to download csv
}
```

here's an example of that :

```js
function exportCSV()
{
    var csv = [];

    [...document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="text_box"]')].forEach(function(e){
      csv.push(e.value);
    });

    console.log(csv.join(",")); // Function ahead to download csv
}

exportCSV();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text_box_1" value="first"/>
<input type="text" id="text_box_2" value="second" />
<input type="text" id="another_text_box" value="third" />
<input type="text" id="another_text_box_2" value="fourth" />
<input type="text" id="text_box_3" value="fifth" />
<input type="text" id="text_box_4" value="sixth" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var textBoxArr = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for(i=0; i<textBoxArr.length; i++) {
//store textbox value here;
    alert("value is: "+textBoxArr[i].value);
}
```

The above code snippet will iterate through all `input type = "text"` and get corresponding value ; which we can as: `csv.push(textBoxArr[i].value)` no need to work based on ID

Comment: Try to explain your solution a little so OP can understand maybe :)

Comment: The above code snippet will iterate through all input type = "text" and get corresponding value ;  which we can as: csv.push(textBoxArr[i].value)
no need to work based on ID

Comment: Better to add your precision inside the anwser so everyone can see it :) I edited your anwser

Comment: Okay; Thank you :)